# Show that the Volterra operator have dense range.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $V: C([0,1]) \rightarrow C([0,1])$ be defined by
$$ V f(x) = \int\limits_0^x f(t) dt.$$
Show that V has dense range and find the transpose of V.

V has dense range: Since the polynomials are dense in $C([0,1])$, V is dense.
The transpose $V^*: C^*([0,1]) \rightarrow C^*([0,1])$ i guess. How does a map between those spaces look like and how do I find it?

Comment: This is not right since all $g$ in the range of $V$ satisfy $g(0) = 0$. Hence the closure of the range of $V$ is not all $C([0,1])$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operator $V$ doesn't have dense range. Indeed, take $g\in \mathrm{im}(V)$, then for some $f\in C([0,1])^*$ we have
$$
g(x)=\int\limits_{0}^{x} f(t)d\lambda(t)
$$
where $\lambda$ is a Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. Hence $g(0)=0$, and $\Vert 1_{[0,1]}-g\Vert_\infty\geq |1_{[0,1]}(0)-g(0)|=1$. Since $g\in\mathrm{Im}(V)$ is arbitrary we have $1_{[0,1]}\notin\mathrm{cl}(\mathrm{im}(V))$, so image of $V$ is not dense.

By [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem) there is isometric isomorphism between $C([0,1])^*$ and $M([0,1])$ the space of signed $\sigma$-additive bounded regular Borel measures. This isomorphism is the following
$$
I:M([0,1])\to C([0,1])^*:\mu\mapsto\left(f\mapsto \int\limits_{0}^{1}f(t)d\mu(t)\right)
$$
Moreover if for $\varphi\in C([0,1])^*$ we denote $\mu=I^{-1}(\varphi)$ then
$$
\varphi(f)=\int\limits_{0}^{1}f(t)d\mu(t)
$$
In this case adjoint operator $V^*$ is given by equalities
$$
V^*(\varphi)(f)=
\varphi(V(f))=
\int\limits_{0}^{1}V(f)(x)d\mu(x)=
\int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{0}^{x} f(t)d\lambda(t)d\mu(x)=
\int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{t}^{1} f(t)d\mu(x)d\lambda(t)=
$$
$$
\int\limits_{0}^{1}f(t)\int\limits_{t}^{1} d\mu(x)d\lambda(t)=
\int\limits_{0}^{1}f(t)\mu([t,1])d\lambda(t)\tag{1}
$$
Consider measure $\nu\in M([0,1])$ given by
$$
\nu(A)=\int\limits_{A}\mu([t,1])d\lambda(t)\tag{2}
$$
where $A$ some Borel set on $[0,1]$. Then $(1)$ can be written as
$$
V^*(\varphi)(f)=\int\limits_{0}^{1}f(t)\mu([t,1])d\lambda(t)=I(\nu)(f)
$$
Hence $V^*$ maps functional $\varphi\in C^*([0,1])$ to the functional $I(\nu)$.

But if you identify $C([0,1])^*$ with $M([0,1])$ as usually people do the result can be formulated much easier: $V^*$ maps measure $\mu$ to measure $\nu$ given by $(2)$.